# How to automatically format drools files with Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, formatting, drools

For our current project we have code formatting rules for java and xml files.  Is there some way to configure Eclipse to format drools files (*.drl)?

Comment: Is there one available today?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know you can't. The current plugin doesn't format the DRL files. It can be a very good contribution to the project :)
Cheers