# How to configure Eclipse to format drools files *.drl?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, drools

I have a drl file that needs proper formatting including indentation. Is there a plugin for that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [drools plugin for Eclipse](http://www.jboss.org/drools/downloads) or [JBoss tools](http://www.jboss.org/tools) (indludes the drools plugin).

Comment: I already have this plugin configured but I don't see any button that formats or at least indents correctly the drl code.

Answer (score 0):

See [How to automatically format drools files with Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723078/how-to-automatically-format-drools-files-with-eclipse)

Currently the drools plugin does not support formatting. (Which is a shame)